# How to select a path of url in the Adblock plus element filter?

Tags: adblock

First of all, I apologize for my poor English.

`cafe.naver.com#?#div#content-area :is(tr,li):-abp-has(span.mem-level>img[src$="_999.gif"])`
I wrote a filter like the one above.

but I want to select only the below url path.
cafe.naver.com/steamindiegame ...

`cafe.naver.com/steamindiegame#?#div#content-area :is(tr,li):-abp-has(span.mem-level>img[src$="_999.gif"])`
So I tried the above, but I get an error.

how to fix it????

e.g.) I want to select emphasized urls

- http://cafe.naver.com
- ***https://cafe.naver.com/steamindiegame***
- ***http://cafe.naver.com/steamindiegame***
- https://cafe.naver.com/joonggonara
- ***https://cafe.naver.com/steamindiegame/3559974***
- http://cafe.naver.com/joonggonara/862324099
- https://cafe.naver.com/malzero/175438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=48613

> The hiding filters are working on domain, so the answer is: No.

It seems impossible